# Cannot renew Qouta in Azure API Managment

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Actually I'm trying to re-new a quota for specific client because he exceed the quota, but in same time i don't want to reset it for all client only for this one , Also without changing the subscription key .

the code below is not working fine i try to test it , does not reaching the limit exactly sometimes reaching more than the quota and sometimes less than and it's not small different it's huge different

```
<choose>
        <when condition="@(context.Subscription.Id == "")">
            <quota-by-key calls="20" renewal-period="500" counter-key="@(context.Subscription.Key)" />
        </when>
   <otherwise />
</choose>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the same policy at my end by creating a new subscription key and it worked as expected for me.

Please verify if you are using the correct subscription id. By default, APIM takes the **Built-in all-access subscription**  subscription key if you haven't provided **ocp-apim-subscription-key** in the request header for any other subscription key. For **Built-in all-access subscription**, subscription id value is **master**.

You can check the subscription key name and id which is being used by your API with the help of below policy-

```
<set-variable  name="ID"  value="@(context.Subscription.Id)"  />
<set-variable  name="Name"  value="@(context.Subscription.Name)"  />
```

*You can see the values in Trace*

[image]

[image]

**Policy**

```
<choose>
<when  condition="@(context.Subscription.Id== "test")">
<quota-by-key  calls="2"  renewal-period="300"  counter-key="@(context.Subscription.Key)"  />
</when>
</choose>
```

**Test**

[image]

[image]

**Trace**

[image]

[image]

You can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1351117/azure-apim-define-rate-limit-and-quota-limit-polic) too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i don't want to change subsecription i want to use same subsecription .

Comment: Same subscription as in **Built-in all-access subscription** ?

Comment: Yes same subscription to avoid changing on client environment

Comment: In this case you need to pass the subscription I'd as master in your policy, it will work

Comment: can you give me please a hint how to do it ?

Comment: add <when  condition="@(context.Subscription.Id== "master")">